# SED command to remove last digits in a word and replace with a sequence

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a pattern like.. can someone help me to figure it out

```
abc1 17898 8779 
abc1 68579 7879
abc2 78794 8989
abc2 97857 9897
abc3 79850 9905
.
.
.
abc120  84889 9897
abc121  87898 7879
abc121  87898 7879
abc121  87898 7879
abc122  87898 7879
abc122  87898 7879
```

I want to remove the digits next to abc and give them a proper sequence,

which should be like this

```
abc1 17898 8779 
abc2 68579 7879
abc3 78794 8989
abc4 97857 9897
abc5 79850 9905
..
.
.
abc120  84889 9897
abc121  87898 7879
abc122  87898 7879
abc123  87898 7879
abc124  87898 7879
abc125  87898 7879
```

Comment: sed    's/abc[0-9]/abc*[0+] /g' in.txt > out.txt

where I assumed that [0-9] is the number of digits next to abc and *[0+] can be a incremental to replace the digits with previous

Comment: When posting sample input/output, don't use `...` to represent continuations as it makes the example untestable. We want some concrete test case that we can test a potential solution against, not an idea/suggestion that we could use to create our own test case. sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, btw, that is all. If you need to do anything else, including math, then just use awk.

Answer (score 1):

This is much easier with `awk` than `sed`:

```
awk -F 'abc' '{sub(/^[0-9]+/, "", $2); print FS NR $2}' file
abc1 17898 8779
abc2 68579 7879
abc3 78794 8989
abc4 97857 9897
abc5 79850 9905
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{sub(/[0-9]+/,NR)}1' file
abc1 17898 8779
abc2 68579 7879
abc3 78794 8989
abc4 97857 9897
abc5 79850 9905
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `perl`, which supports basic arithmetic (as opposed to `sed`). For example:

```
perl -pe 's/\B\d*\b/$./' filename
```

Here `\b` matches a word boundary and `\B` matches an empty string that is not a word boundary, so `\B\d*\b` matches the group of numbers (or empty string) at the end of the first word in the line, and `$.` is the current line number -- Perl helpfully keeps track of it for us already.

Alternatively,

```
perl -pe 's/^abc\d*/abc$./' filename
```

is more in line with your previous attempt.

If there are lines in the  input that don't match the `abc` pattern and the counter should not be increased for them,

```
perl -pe 's/^abc\d*/"abc" . ++$n/e' filename
```

allows you to do the counting yourself.

Comment: Need help.. I want to words starting with abc from each line and display.

#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
open (tran_file, "in.txt" );
open (OUT, " > out.txt");
$count = 0;
while ($line = <tran_file>)
{
   chomp ($line);
   if ($line =~ m/^abc\d*/)    ### matching the word abc.
    {     
     if ($line =~ /\s(\d*)\s+\s(\d+\.\d+)\s+\s(\d+\.\d+)\s(.+)/)

 ### trying to divide the content in the line and extract the first word in all the line ie., abc1 
       
  {
    

               print OUT " $1 \n";

            }
    }

}
  
close (tran_file);